# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause'

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

Necesito saber ¿cuál es la forma para hacer referencia una columna especifica sobre la tabla en la que hago relación en consulta?

Relación:

```
public function users()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)->withTimestamps();
}

public function roles()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

Consulta:

```
//Usuarios con roles         // traer solo usuarios con id 1,2,3,4,5

$info = User::with('roles')->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])->get();
```

Usando la misma consulta, quiero añadir un where, en donde busque el "name" que le pase, pero de la tabla roles, algo asi:

```
$info = User::with('roles')->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])->where('name', '=','Ulises')->get();
```

Error en la salida:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select from `status` where `id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and `name` = Ulises)

**¿Si no es asi, como hago referencia entonces  a la segunda tabla?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente debes modificar lo que pasas al método `with` para establecer una consulta interna que apunte a *roles* de está forma:

```
User::with(['roles' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', '=','rol');
}])->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])->get();
```

Establecemos un array donde el nombre de la relación es la clave y el valor es una función donde construimos la consulta interna que filtre.

- [Aquí puedes leer más](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

Comment: me perdí. La sentencia que puso el OP pone dos cláusulas sobre el modelo `User`, ninguna sobre `Roles`. Tampoco creo que haya un rol llamado Ulises. Creo que si el OP resolvió su problema con tu respuesta falta que edite un poco la pregunta para que le sirva a cualquier visitante con un problema similar

Comment: @fflabs entiendo perfecto tu punto pero para la respuesta me base en esto: *Usando la misma consulta, quiero añadir un where, en donde busque el "name" que le pase, pero de la tabla roles, algo asi:* igual entonces haría falta arrobarlo y que nos comente al respecto, ya que como te expongo *esto fue lo que entendí*

Comment: De ser así, le comentaré que o bien edite la pregunta para aclarar y/o publique su propia solución (*marcandola como aceptada*), agradezco tu observación 

Comment: Ah, tienes toda la razón, no ví la parte *pero en la tabla Roles*, retiro mi acotación